# php dynamic array creation

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have this situation:

A db table 'pageitems' with

```
zone | text
------------
ZONE1  text1
ZONE2  text2
ZONE3  text3
ZONE3  text4
```

and inside a foreach loop like this

```
foreach($pageitems as $items) {
...
}
```

I want to obtain an array like this

```
Array
 (
    [ZONE1] => Array(
        [0] => text1
    )

    [ZONE2] => Array
    (
        [0] => text2
    )

    [ZONE3] => Array
    (
        [0] => text3,
        [1] => text4
    )

 )
```

How to obtain this?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you don't need that comma after "text3"

```
$arr = array();
foreach($pageitems as $items) {
    $arr[$items['zone']][] = $items['text'];
}
```